# Inserting boolean value in SQLite DB

Tags: android, sqlite

I have read that SQLite doesnot support boolean datatype instead we need to use ***Integer 1(true) and 0(false)***. So i have Used the Integer and it's getting inserted correctly but when i am retreiving the rows based on the comparision i am not getting the rows. I don't understand why.

The snippets are like this:

```
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Shipyard";
private static final String SHIP_TYPE = "shipType";
private static final String SHIP_STATUS_TYPE = "shipStatusType";

 String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE "+SHIP_TYPE+ " = "+ "'active' AND "+SHIP_STATUS_TYPE+" = 1";
```

Here the **SHIP_STATUS_TYPE** should be equal to **1** which is boolean in my case . But I am getting zero rows. But in mine Db there is column with **shipStatusType = 1**

I am creating table like this

```
String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + SHIP_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," + SHIP_TITLE + " TEXT,"
                +SHIP_STATUS_TYPE+" INTEGER)";
```

> Here I have set SHIP_STATUS_TYPE data type as INTEGER which is kind of
>   boolean in my case(0\1)

Now the point is I am comparing it wrong or some else thing is there

Also in the POJO class I am setting shipStatusType Like this:

```
private int shipStatusType;
// Getter and setter
_shipment.setShipStatusType(1)
```

This is how i am inserting the shipment into the DB

```
 public void addShipment(Shipment shipment) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(SHIP_ID, shipment.getShipmentId());
            values.put(SHIP_TITLE, shipment.getShipTitle());
            values.put(SHIP_CREATION_TIME, shipment.getCreatedAt());
            values.put(SHIP_STATUS_TYPE, shipment.getShipStatusType());

            // Inserting Row
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question - if you run the query without the `AND "+SHIP_STATUS_TYPE+" = 1"` do you get any results?

Comment: yeah i am getting the result without SHIP_STATUS_TYPE

Comment: and what about if you make it AND "+SHIP_STATUS_TYPE+" = 0"

Comment: same for both the cases 0/1, I am not getting the result

Comment: can you try to add apostrophes around the digit?   Liek this: `....+SHIP_STATUS_TYPE+" = '1'"`

Comment: post your insert query

Comment: Still not working...

Comment: It sounds like you aren't actually setting SHIP_STATUS_TYPE to 1, because as far as I can see your SELECT query is absolutely correct. I suspect your INSERT/UPDATE is wrong in this instance.

Comment: I have posted my edited anser with insert also

Comment: If you do a `SELECT * FROM Shipyard`, **does it show all (or at least some) of the records having a shipStatusType**?

Comment: Yeah it's showing the records and the shipstatusType as either 0/1 ... I have checked in the Log.

Comment: Now try `SELECT * FROM Shipyard WHERE shipstatusType = 1`

Comment: Hah... Its not returning any thing.. I tried the above query

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of whatever you are using to perform both queries and the results?

Comment: Thanks @AlastairCampbell .. I think now its working the query with SELECT * FROM Shipyard WHERE shipstatusType = 1 . Might be some problem with my code .. I will figure it out ... thanx for the patience

Answer (score 0):

Why bother yourself with the SQL when all you really wanna do is deal with the data objects?

There are a lot of ORM libraries that abstract the SQL process and enable you to deal only with the java objects.

I myself usually use [GreenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/) for Android projects.